# where to add -g -O0 debug flags for lldb

Tags: debugging, lldb

I've been told that -g, -O0 tell the compiler not to optimize the code, in order to generate the executable the clearest possible. If I need to create explicitly the object file with -c option, do I have to add debug flags in that step or in linking, or both?

Answer (score 0):

`-g` tells the compiler to generate debug information, `-O0` tells it to not optimize the code; those two options can be used independently from each other. In order to generate straightforward code, it suffices to use the `-O0` flag in the compiling (`-c`) step, since that's where the code is generated. Whether `-g` is needed in the linking step depends on the toolchain - it is not needed with a GNU linker.